# How to download a file from URL (downloadable link) from Outlook 365 using Power Automate (Cloud)

Tags: outlook, powerapps, power-automate

I am getting dozens of Emails with a downloadable link one per week. Every time I have to click on that link and download starts immediately (I am not seeing the webpage at all).
Is there a way to get this automated using **Power Automate Cloud**, so I can have all my links (.csv) saved in a specific folder?

We do have Premium connectors.

Dummy Email Link with an Excel file:
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qZfij-WlsjrWiA4pW_2Qczhhee0mKRxS

This is what I did but somehow is not working properly:

[image]

Comment: So are you using desktop or cloud flows?  You've tagged both.

Comment: @Skin Sorry, Cloud!

Comment: I don't think we can really help unless you provide a URL that we can test with ourselves.  Usually, you need a REST API that provides you with the relevant file contents.  Not sure if you can provide a link so we can test ourselves.

Comment: This link explains something different, but still I cant figure it out.
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Automatically-download-a-file-that-is-in-an-url-link-inside-the/m-p/761142#M105122

Comment: If you want our help, you need to provide an example email with the exact contents so we can parse it. Someone else’s question on another community doesn’t help. There are two parts to your question, getting the url from the email and then actually downloading the contents. They both have their challenges.

Comment: @Skin Okay..I updated it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253789/discussion-between-skin-and-mmvv).

Comment: I actually supplied you with an answer but it's not complete so I deleted it.  That file download link, put simply, isn't able to be actioned by a simple HTTP call.  You'll need another way.  I do however have a way to extract the URL's from your email if you're interested in that.

Comment: @Skin Okay...if you have some solution please post it, I might find it suitable too. I am interested indeed.

Comment: Done, you can see it now.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a premium licence, you could look at using the `Advanced Data Operations` (https://www.statesolutions.com.au/pricing) connector and the `Regex Matches` operation to achieve your desired result.

You can sign up for a free trial and see if it fits the bill, also, it's very cheap for what you get.

[image: Test Flow]

That (very simple) example runs some regex and looks for all URL's in the `Body Preview` of the incoming email.

This is the regex pattern used (which may need to be tweaked, you'll work that out though I guess) ...

```
\b((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^\s$.?#].[^\s]*)\b
```

... the end result is an array of all URL's ...

This is the text I used in the email for testing purposes ...

> This is the text to see if I can extract https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qZfij-WlsjrWiA4pW_2Qczhhee0mKRxS url's from any given text.
>
> To test with other URL’s, let’s try inserting https://www.microsoft.com and see if it also pulls that.

... and this was the end result ...

```
[
  "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qZfij-WlsjrWiA4pW_2Qczhhee0mKRxS",
  "https://www.microsoft.com"
]
```

[image: Result]